# How to SQL JOIN on concatenated columns in MS Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, concatenation, matching

I have 2 tables where column X and Y are concatenated to represent a unique identifier. I want to find all rows in tableB that do not exist in tableA and add them into tableC.

```
-------tableA--------   // tableA is a master refernce table with all names so far
|__X__|__Y__|_name__|
|  3  |  7  | Mary  |
|  3  |  2  | Jaime |

-------tableB--------   // tableB is an input file with all daily names (some repeats already exist in tableA)
|__X__|__Y__|_name__|
|  2  |  5  | Smith |
|  3  |  7  | Mary  |

-------tableC--------   // tableC is a temporary holding table for new names
|__X__|__Y__|_name__|
|     |     |       |

DESIRED RESULT: 
-------tableC--------   // tableB - tableA = tableC
|__X__|__Y__|_name__|
|  2  |  5  | Smith |
```

I want to match rows based on a concatenated X+Y value. My SQL query so far looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO tableC 
SELECT * FROM tableA
LEFT JOIN tableB
   ON tableA.X & table.B = tableB.X & tableB.Y
WHERE tableB.X & tableB.Y IS null
```

However, this does not give me the intended result. I cannot use EXISTS as my actual data set is very big. Could anyone give me suggestions?

Comment: why do you think `exists` can't be used with a big dat set?

Comment: It can, but its not realistic for my purposes. It takes way too long

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the slowness is caused by `exists`. Your query is probably slow because you're trying to use concatenation to match multiple columns. Use `and` instead and make sure you have a composite index on (x,y):

This will select all unique rows in tableB that don't have the same (x,y) value in tableA. Note that any rows with the same x,y but a different name will show up in the result (i.e. 2,5,Joe would also appear). If you don't want that, then you have to group by x,y and decide which name you want in case of duplicate x,y but different name.

```
select distinct x,y,name 
from tableB b
where not exists (
  select 1 from tableA a
  where a.x = b.x
  and a.y = b.y
)
```